# add validations to inherited model in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model-view-controller

The code is simply inherited model. 
But unfortunately validation does not work. The idea is to select fathers from parrots. When I loop @fathers - it shows all parrots but should select only those who have age more than 12 and so on.  Or maybe I do something wrong?

Model

```
  class Father < Parrot
  has_many :parrots
    validates :age, :numericality => { :greater_than => 12}
    validates :tribal, :acceptance => true
    validates_inclusion_of :sex, :in => %w( Male )
  end
```

view

```
  <% @fathers.each do || %>
    <%= f.name %> 
  <% end %>
```

controller

```
  def index
    @parrots = Parrot.all
    @fathers = Father.all
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation criteria has nothing to do with how data is queried, just that it passes the defined criteria before object is written to the database.  Are you saying that `Father` object doesn't perform the validation and persists invalid data?

Are you sure that all of the father parrots are being saved through the `Father` object?  You should also have a `type` column in your `parrots` column that has either 'Parrot' or 'Father' value.  When you execute `Father.all` it should be running a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM parrots WHERE type='Father';
```

filtering out parrots that were not saved through the `Father` object.

If you just need to pull `Parrots` that match `Father` criteria from the DB you can use scopes:

```
class Father < ActiveRecord::Base
   self.table_name = 'parrots'
   default_scope { where("age > 12 and tribal = 'true' and sex='Male'")}
   #whatever else
end
```

Here's additional information on [Single Table Inheritance](http://blog.arkency.com/2013/07/sti/) and [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Comment: Thx. Thats the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Validations are used when the Father is saved.  The "type" column in the db will determine the class.  Be sure that is set correctly.

But, is `Father` really a separate class?  Or just a `Parrot` with certain attributes.  It seems that Parrot.all would include all Fathers.

It may be a scope.

```
class Parrot < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :fathers, -> { where(:sex => 'Male').where('age >= 12').where(:tribal => true) }

end
```

Then you can get fathers by

```
@fathers = Parrot.fathers
```

Comment: Thx. Thats the solution.